# Choose join table from column value

Tags: sql, join

Here a simplification of my database structure:

```
+-----------+    +-----------+    +-------------+
|   data    |    |  int_val  |    | float_val   |
+-----------+    +-----------+    +-------------+
| data_id   |    |  val_id   |    |  val_id     |
|  type     |    |  int_val  |    | float_val   |
| value_ref |    +-----------+    +-------------+
+-----------+
```

`data.value_ref` is not declared as foreign key, but it is. The idea is to choose which table to join (`float_val` or `int_val`) using `data.type column`.

Can I do this with a single query?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to select, I believe.

Comment: can you please give some sample data from these tables and the desired output?

Comment: What is the data type of the column you want back?  A column can only have a single data type (barring unusual SQL extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with outer joins and a CASE WHEN:

```
select
    case when type = 'int' 
         then int_val.int_val
         else float_val.float_val
    end
from
    data
    left join int_val on data.value_ref=val_id
    left join float_val on data.value_ref=val_id
```

This assumes that value_ref will exist in either int_val or float_val, but not both.

Comment: But it doesn't work if I use string_val table. I get `type integer and varchar did not match`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: postgresql. It only works if i limit the case to integer and float data. postgre error 42804 DATATYPE MISMATCH

Comment: If you're mixing numeric an character, then you'll have to convert the numerics.  Try `cast(int_val.int_val as varchar)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    data.id,
    COALESCE(CAST(int_val.int_val AS FLOAT), float_val.float_val) AS value
FROM data
LEFT JOIN int_val
       ON int_val.val_id = data.value_ref
      AND data.type = 'int'
LEFT JOIN float_val
       ON float_val.val_id = data.value_ref
      AND data.type = 'float'
```